# When does an iframe START to load on a page?

Tags: html, dom, iframe

Quick question. I'm not interested in knowing when a iframe has finished loading. I'm curious as to when the request from the iframe begins.

Is it inline (async or synchronous), after DOM is ready, or after images are loaded? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inline and asynchronous. Just like an image.

Answer (score 0):

The "onload" event on an iframe will fire when the page has been fetched, but before the DOM is ready. This means when the "HTML" has been fetched, not images, scripts, stylesheets etc. These occur during DOM processing.